# Having trouble Joining 2 Tables

Tags: sql, join

I have tried what I possibly could but am having a really hard time figuring out the problem with this query.

When I execute the query, it brings repeated rows from the table `deleted_messages`. Am joining the `private_messages` table with the `deleted_messages`. The `deleted_messages` hold those messages that have been completely deleted by a user.

```
SELECT private_messages.EA_MID
    ,private_messages.EA_to
    ,private_messages.EA_from
    ,private_messages.EA_DateSent
    ,private_messages.EA_Subject
    ,private_messages.EA_Message
    ,private_messages.EA_Opened
    ,private_messages.EA_RecipientDeleted
    ,private_messages.EA_SenderDeleted
    ,deleted_messages.EA_DMID
    ,deleted_messages.EA_UID
    ,deleted_messages.EA_MID
    ,deleted_messages.EA_Date
FROM deleted_messages
LEFT JOIN private_messages ON (deleted_messages.EA_UID = private_messages.EA_to)
    OR (deleted_messages.EA_UID = private_messages.EA_from)
WHERE (
        (
            private_messages.EA_to = '$uid'
            AND private_messages.EA_RecipientDeleted = '1'
            )
        OR (
            private_messages.EA_from = '$uid'
            AND private_messages.EA_SenderDeleted = '1'
            )
        )
```

Comment: Come on, where is everybody.. i need help here. Please

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT /* field omitted  */
FROM deleted_messages
LEFT JOIN private_messages 
    ON (deleted_messages.EA_UID = private_messages.EA_to 
         AND private_messages.EA_RecipientDeleted = '1')
    OR (deleted_messages.EA_UID = private_messages.EA_from 
         AND private_messages.EA_SenderDeleted = '1')
WHERE /* omitted */
```